# Power Query Replace Value not working. Using #" " around the Column Name?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

(VERY new to Power Query)  I am trying to replace a value in a column based on two criteria.  I created a helper column, and the IF statement for the two criteria works, but when I try to copy+paste it into the ReplaceValue statement, it doesn't work.

I noticed in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpZTPEBHQOY approximately 4:10 that he types in the Columns as just [Smoking_Allowed] (vs [#"Smoking_Allowed" with the # and quotes).

When I create my helper column using Add Column > Custom Column, it puts my column names with the # and quotes, and as mentioned, it works.  I tried my ReplaceValue statement both with and without the # and quotes, but neither way works.

Any ideas?  Not sure I can post my file without some major clean up as its for work.  Here's the code with a couple changes (using the version with the # and quotes as PQ will give me syntax error without to obscure work related info.

= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Custom for Sales Clean up",
each [Department],
each if [#"Account#"] = 12345 and [#"Memo/Description"] = "Example Description" then "Sales" else [Department],
Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Department"})

EDIT: Anonymized the account/description.

Answer (score 0):

`#"..."` is most often used for names that contain spaces like the reference to the previous step you have in your example: `#"Added Custom for Sales Clean up"`. This lets the code know that this is all a single object.

When you're referring to a column, since it's contained in square brackets, `[ ]`, this isn't usually necessary since the brackets group it all together. However, if you have certain characters in a column name, you'll need to 'escape' them with `#"..."` again. Since you have `#` and `/` in your column names, you need to use that syntax.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that.  The #"..." didn't make a difference either way - both ways failed to make the necessary replace value.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: There isn't actually any error message (when I use the #"...").  It just doesn't change the value (leaves it null rather than replacing it with "Sales".  I believe all the other values in the column are left alone (the table has over 1,000 rows).  I didn't notice any wholescale changing of the other values (which are correct and should be left alone)

Comment: It sounds like one of your two conditions isn't true for some reason but I can't tell why without looking at it.

Comment: But the two conditions work in the helper column.  Here's the helper column:
= Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "ConditionTrue Sales", each if [#"Account #"] = 12345 and [#"Memo/Description"] = "Example Description" then "Yes" else "-")

Comment: I've tested it on my computer with some sample data and it works as expected. Double-check that you are getting an exact match with your `Memo/Description` since M is case-sensitive.

Comment: I mean, I copied the words from the cell in Memo/Description (there's only one cell that matches these two conditions of account and memo/description) into the helper column (and that works), and then copied the statement beginning with "each and ending with the description endquote (just before the "then").

Could this part be wrong?  It doesn't seem to reference the department column, but then that part in the guy's video is also a weird rerence that goes away once he gets rid of the helper column.


= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Custom for Sales Clean up"

Comment: Ran out of space so adding this 
... that goes away once he gets rid of the helper column. ...
(I still have the helper column since I'm following his steps and not ready to remove it since I didn't get the "all good to go" with my formula

Comment: OK this is weird.  I just realized that it seems like a new Query is being created something like after the attempt to replace with the "Sales" value.  So now I have 3 queries instead of just the one (maybe from 2 attempts at this?).    Anyway, in these two other queries and the resulting sheet/table they create, it IS now replacing the value in the Department to "Sales".  Not sure where to go with this, but it's a clue.

Answer (score 0):

The clouds open up and the angles sing...

Account# is actually Account # (with a space).  SHM.